# is a star followed by a class name defining an array? c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, dynamic-arrays

I programmed several years ago, in which I wrote everything in the main function instead of using classes and other functions so I'm pretty confused. I have a project that has a specified format, and the way the array is defined is confusing me. I initially thought that xArray was a dynamic array, but when I try to assign a size to it, it gives error E0513 "a value of type "int *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type Group1

```
Group1{
int x,y;
}

Group2{
int a,b;
Group1* xArray; 
}

void main{ 
Group1 g1;

int length;
cout <<"enter the length"<< endl;
cin >> length;
g1.xArray = new int[length];
}
```

so basically, I have a few questions, 1. what exactly is xArray(pointer? array?) 2. if it is a dynamic array, can I assign a length to it (which would be an input variable) outside the class where it's defined?

Comment: The error is correct. `group1* xArray;` xArray needs to point to group1 object(s) not int(s). `g1.xArray = new int[length];` should be `g1.xArray = new Group1[length];` also capitalization matters. `group1` is different from `Group1` I assume that was a typo.

Comment: `*` in this context designates a pointer in C++. For more information see your C++ textbook.

Comment: Which book are you using to learn C++? There are a number of basic syntax errors in your code, in constructs which should be explained in your book.

Comment: How many times do I have to say it? "You can't learn C++ by trial and error!"

Comment: this isn't for a class, its for a job. He gave me an assignment which I did in python. He said he wanted it in a C family language so I used c++ vectors. Then he gave me this template to use where HE defined the classes and said to use dynamic arrays. In the example I provided, my only contribution to the code was the main function.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are attempting to assign an array of one type, to a pointer of another. Here is a simpler example:

```
struct OneInt {
   int a;
}
...
OneInt *o = new int[5]; // This cannot work, int is not the same type as OneInt
OneInt *o = new OneInt[5]; // This will allocate memory for an array of type OneInt
```

But honestly, you should do neither. You are looking for a dynamically sized vector, so c++ helps you by providing `std::vector`:

```
Group2{
  int a,b;
  std::vector<Group1> xArray; // By using an array, the memory is initialized and 
                              // handled automatically
}

Group2 g;
g.xArray.resize(5);
```

This way, we don't need to mess around with `new` and `delete` and we have better, exception safe, encapsulated code. This is a technique of modern c++ called Resource Aquisition is Initialization (RAII).